# Display dynamic contents in 3-column layout in HTML integrating editor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am unknown to the CSS world. I need to integrate a Markdown editor (SimpleMDE) in an app.

Since I want the preview to be available all the time and side by side, I have added some JavaScript to click the side-by-side preview button using JQuery.

I want to have a third **column sticking towards the right called notes** which will have list of other items (says `li`s or `divs`).

Depending on whether the preview has been set or not, the ratio of editor-preview-notes and editor-notes will be 40%-40%-20% or 80-20%.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/simplemde/latest/simplemde.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./editor-style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="editor-row">
            <div class="col-md-4" id="editor-container">
                <textarea id="markdown-editor"></textarea> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" id="notes-sidebar">
                <div class="note-card">Note 1</div>
                <div class="note-card">Note 2</div>
                <div class="note-card">Note 3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/simplemde/latest/simplemde.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/markdown-it@12.1.0/dist/markdown-it.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./markdown-editor.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            initializeEditor();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and JS

```js
// https://github.com/sparksuite/simplemde-markdown-editor


var md = new markdownit();
var simplemde;
var debounceRenderPreview;

function initializeEditor() {

    var debounceMarkdownToHtml = _.debounce(function() {
        // Your API call logic here
        var markdownContent = simplemde.value();
        var convertedHtml = md.render(markdownContent);
        return convertedHtml;
    }, 250);
    
    simplemde = new SimpleMDE({
        element: $("#markdown-editor")[0],
        spellChecker: false,
        autofocus: true,
        fullscreen: false,
        sideBySideFullscreen: false,
        autosave: {
            enabled: true,
            uniqueId: "MyUniqueID",
            delay: 4000,
        },
        previewRender: debounceMarkdownToHtml,
    }); 

    $(".editor-toolbar .fa.fa-columns").click();
}
```

The problem also being that the preview div appears after loading.

(Googling, I have tried changing my CSS to use 33% width, display none/block but no gain.)

```css
.editor-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#editor-container {
    width: 40%;
    order: 1; /* Place editor first in the flex order */
}

#notes-sidebar {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    padding: 10px;
    order: 3; /* Place notes sidebar last in the flex order */
}

.note-card {
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Please direct me on how to approach this one.